# Как подключить два шрифта через CSS?

Tags: шрифты, css

Как подключить два шрифта через CSS? Нужно подключить ArialNarrow Bold и AGAalenBold Roman. И еще вопрос где можно найти эти шрифты?

Comment: Скачал оба шрифта с расширением файла ttf. Пытаюсь их конвертировать на сайте http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, но выдает ошибку **The font is corrupt and can not be converted**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ArialNarrow Bold;
    src: url(ArialNarrowBold.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: AGAalenBold Roman;
    src: url(AGAalenBoldRoman.ttf);
}
.class1 {
    font-family: "ArialNarrow Bold";
}
.class2 {
    font-family: "AGAalenBold Roman";
}
```

**[Прекрасные шрифты посредством @font-face [habrahabr]](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64596/)**

Answer (score 2):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face

http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/font-face-non-standart-fonts-on-css.html

шрифты нужно поискать в интрнете
для конвертации можно использовать:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

http://www.web-font-generator.com/

в css файл

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'шрифт1';
    src: url('шрифт1.eot');
    src: url('шрифт1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('шрифт1.woff') format('woff'),
         url('шрифт1.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('шрифт1.svg#cuprumffuregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}   
@font-face {
    font-family: 'шрифт2';
    src: url('шрифт2.eot');
    src: url('шрифт2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('шрифт2.woff') format('woff'),
         url('шрифт2.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('шрифт2.svg#cuprumffuregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Скачал оба шрифта с расширением файла ttf. Пытаюсь их конвертировать на сайте http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, но выдает ошибку **The font is corrupt and can not be converted**.

Comment: Попробуйте другим сервисом

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Font_name"; 
  src: url("Fontname.woff2") format("woff2"), 
       url("Fontname.woff") format("woff"); 
  font-weight: 400; 
  font-style: normal; 
}

@font-face { 
  font-family: "Font_name"; 
  src: url("Fontname.woff2") format("woff2"), 
       url("Fontname.woff") format("woff"); 
  font-weight: 600; 
  font-style: bold; 
}
```